# Change the number of items/products per page in broadleaf

Tags: solr, broadleaf-commerce

Where can I change the number of items listed per page? I saw that the default was 15 and ran into a post ([here](http://aspiresoftware.in/blog/java/solr-search-customization-in-broadleaf.html)) stating that it is customizable and referenced as pageSize, but I have no clue where to change its value from.

I would like to increase it when listing products from a certain category or for the search page.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is controlled by 2 properties within Broadleaf:

```
web.defaultPageSize=15
web.maxPageSize=100
```

The `web.defaultPageSize` is what is restricting it to 15. This is currently set in `site/src/main/resources/common.properties` and `api/src/main/resources/common.properties` so making an update to those files should let you change this.